# Docker reg import

Tags: windows, docker, fonts, registry

I'm creating a docker that needs some special fonts (Japanese in fact), I copied all fonts to respective folder but is not sufficient, they need to be registered. I create a reg file to do that in a simple way and inside the container works well (the fonts are installed), but when I tried to include it in the docker I've got a warning and also the process appears didn't run and fonts are not registered, I tried with CMD and ENTRYPOINT but nothing

This is part of the docker file:

```
FROM microsoft/aspnet

...

COPY YUGOTH*.TTC C:/windows/fonts/
COPY Fonts.reg /
CMD reg import C:\Fonts.reg
# ENTRYPOINT ["reg import C:\Fonts.reg"]
```

This is the build, in fact it appears that the import runs in a separated container (501a7ca70d2b) and then is removed, this could be the problem?

[image: reg import output]

I could manage to do the same outside the docker using the exec parameter, but I need that the font installation runs automatically not manual.

```
docker exec -d docker_image reg import c:\Fonts.reg
```

This is the way I check when the fonts are registered (inside docker)

```
reg query "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Fonts" /s
```

[image: fonts registered]

and this is the Fonts.reg file

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Fonts]
"YUGOTHB"="YUGOTHB.TTC"
"YUGOTHL"="YUGOTHL.TTC"
"YUGOTHM"="YUGOTHM.TTC"
"YUGOTHR"="YUGOTHR.TTC"
```

Comment: `CMD` just sets the command that will be run when the container starts; it doesn't do anything immediately.  Do you mean to `RUN` that command as part of the image build?

Comment: I guess that a register file should runs when the container starts, well no matters, that do the trick, thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use RUN instead CMD or ENTRYPOINT.